# ERROR while connecting to MySQL by enabling SSL using PASSPHRASE

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : config["mysql"]["connection-limit"],
host            : config["mysql"]["host"],
user            : config["mysql"]["username"],
password        : config["mysql"]["password"],
database        : config["mysql"]["database"],
port            : config["mysql"]["port"],
ssl             : {
    ca          : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/ca.pem'),
    cert        : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client.crt'),
    key         : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client.key')
},
connectTimeout: 100000,
acquireTimeout: 100000
});
```

This is the mysql createpool i am using for connecting with mysql server which have server certs. Since here PASSPHRASE is enabled, i can't find the options on internet with which PASSPHARSE is passed inside ssl {}. Can someone help me with the keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as i posted this question, I found an answer by seeing documentation of mariaDB here - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/nodejs-connection-options/

You just need the keyword "passphrase" and pass your value into it.

Not removing this question because all of the documents with mysql ssl enabled config do not have passphrase enabled. When you will enable the passphrase this ssl {} will be the config.